# :Hover problem in React, not cover all div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover

:hover not cover all div, this images represent my problem.
I need the :hover to cover the whole blue circle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vLeG.jpg)

my code:

In index.

```
return (
        <Container>
            <LogoContainer>
                <ButtonContainer>
                    <ButtonIcon alt='' src={HamburguerIcon} />
                </ButtonContainer>
                <img
                    style={{ cursor: 'pointer', width: '100px' }} 
                    alt=''
                    src={Logo}
                />
            </LogoContainer>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

In style.

```
export const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
    background-color: blue;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    :hover {
            background-color: gray;
    }
`;
```

I try :hover in the ButtonContainer but only ButtonIcon div is covered by :hover

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using SVG or jpg image for hamburger icon.
Try to use .png(transparent) format. or if you are using .svg image please share full svg image.

Comment: I'm already using it in png format. The :hover only applies to the child

Answer (score 0):

Try adding pointer-events styling for child component i.e. ButtonIcon

```
pointer-events: none
```

This will disable the cursor or any event for that Hamburger Icon and it should fix this.

Comment: I tried that way, but the :hover doesn't work either on the parent or on the child.